# Clojure ":import" usage

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between

```
(:import (java.io ByteArrayInputStream) (java.net URL)))
```

and

```
(:import (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream) (java.net.URL))) //Doesn't work
```

(URL. "http://google.com") // URL class name not found error

I'm stumped at the usage between the 2 import declaration even though I know the 2nd declaration doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the full symbol (the 2nd case) you don't need to put parens around it.

```
(:import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream java.net.URL)
```

Tke a look at http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/import